# Exception with dlls:(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040):ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core, Version=2.12.0.0,

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium-webdriver

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am working on a migration project from selenium RC to Selenium webdriver and upgraded my Wedriver dll to version 2.31.2. I have read the posts from stacks for this error and Cleard Bins and cheked .csprj file and done everything still I am getting the same error. Do you have any idea what am I missing here

Comment: Do you have 'ThoughtWorks' dll in your ./bin folder?

Comment: Nop. I try to use clean solution every time. I do not have ThoughtWorks' dll in my bin. I have updated the version in all possible places. Still I am not sure where this version 2.12 is coming from

Comment: Your error message says it all. Your project needs this dll to run, which you haven't included.

Comment: So you mean I should have it in bin folder. Where can I change the version? I have already changed it in .csproj file.

Comment: You should first delete the old dll from the solution reference list. Then add the new reference. You can't just change the csproj file manually.

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e82b5d2-e777-4c24-9e4d-9bc3f74cbaf7/exception-from-hresult-0x80131040?forum=csharpgeneral

You go for this . in web.config version and assembly version must be same.